# Is "Qt Creator 2.4.1 for Windows (53 MB)" includes mingw or clang?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

before i download that big file (it's quite big for internet connection speed in my country), i want to know if that binary files contains the compiler (mingw or clang) also?

or i should download the compiler manually?

or is there any good cross platform IDE with good autocomplete and documentation integration you would recommend for C++?

the download site: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Qt Creator for Windows installer includes Mingw. (Clang isn't really in a usable state at the moment for Windows.) Note however that the included Mingw version may be badly out of date.

Comment: thanks, i've downloaded it, but it cannot build a thing without qt sdk ^^ what a waste..